# SQL: How to get source/target of given coordinates in a line shapefile in PostGIS table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I loaded a line shapefile in PostGIS and used `pgr_createTopology` in pgRouting to make the table routable by adding source and target (assign 2 end nodes of the line source number and target number). The following figure was part of the table:

[image]

Now I have some **coordinates** of end nodes, which belong to lines in the table, and I want to know that what number of **sources/targets** were corresponding to these coordinates.

For example, in the table above, suppose that `259463.392, 2737830.062` was one of end nodes of `line id=1` and `line id=2`, then this coordinate has `source/target=175`

I am newbie to SQL and tried some query but got errors:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) from source;
   FROM public.tc_line15_split;
```

error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 2:        FROM public.tc_line15_split;
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 45
```

---

**UPDATE#1**

I am thinking I could just know what I want if column source/target contain information of node coordinate, but seems not, they are just column containing numbers.

I got the vertices table as below:

[image]

I used the following query to get the table below:

```
select source, target, st_astext(geom) as geom from public.tc_line15_split;
```

[image]

and I am still looking for if I could get my need through the 2 tables above.

So I tried the query below and got 2 lines near the given coordinate:

```
select id from tc_line15_split 
where st_dwithin(geom, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(259463.392, 2737830.062), 3826), 0.1);
```

[image]

and later I found from the table showed in the first figure that the coordinate is source/target=54 of id 170/51, respectively, but it's still inefficient.

I am wondering that is there ways to find the same source/target number, which in this case `line id=51` and `line id=170` both contain, after I found the given coordinate is located between these two lines?

---

**UPDATE#2**

Based on the vertices table, I used the following query to get corresponding source number, which is also point id, of the given coordinate:

```
select id from tc_line15_split_vertices_pgr 
where st_dwithin(the_geom, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(259463.392, 2737830.062), 3826), 0.1);
```

[image]

Comment: What is your end goal in this case?

Comment: Originally I need to use QGIS to find the location of the coordinate and what line (with id) it belong, and then use the table in the post to verify what source/target the coordinate correspond. It is too inefficient. So I just want the process to be much more quick and efficient, and I think it may be achieved.

Comment: Pg_createtopology also creates a vertices table that may already contain the information that you are looking for?

Comment: @shongololo I got the vertices table `tc_line15_split_pgr`, but it only contains id, cnt, chk and geometry, no details about number of source/target.

Comment: `cnt` is the number of edges that have a source / target at that vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to achieve is to figure out how many of the network edges share a common node, then the easiest way to achieve this is to use the vertices table generated by [`pgr_createTopology()`](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/src/topology/doc/pgr_createTopology.html#pgr-create-topology). Per the documentation, it generates a table named the same as your edges table but with `_vertices_pgr` appended.

If you then run the `pgr_analyzeGraph()` method, it will populate the empty columns inside the `my_table_vertices_pgr` table with statistics of each vertex. One of these statistics is the `cnt` column, which shows the number of times a particular vertex is shared by any adjoining edges.

[image]

### Edit:

Regarding some of the other aspects of your question:

The first query in your question returns an error because of syntax, this should work:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM public.tc_line15_split;
```

Regarding Update #1 -> The node coordinates aren't stored explicitly in the vertices table, but you can retrieve them for a specific node id (e.g. `15`) by using this query:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(the_geom))
    FROM tc_line15_split_vertices_pgr
    WHERE id = 15
```

Or, if you simply want X and Y:

```
SELECT ST_X(the_geom), ST_Y(the_geom)
    FROM tc_line15_split_vertices_pgr
    WHERE id = 15
```

Answer (score 1):

To list out the table:

```
select source, target, st_astext(geom) as geom from public.tc_line15_split;
```

You should also have a vertices table with columns like id and geom and if you want to find the nearest node to a location you can used something like:

```
select id from vertices where st_dwithin(geom, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(x,y), 3826), tol);
```

where x,y are you coordinates and tol is a search radius.